# Getting error using libcurl in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, .net, libcurl, v4-printer-driver

I have linked libcurl for linker still getting below error:

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol curl_global_init referenced in function "void _cdecl getRequest(void)"

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: @Qback while building/compiling project